# GET http://localhost:8080/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have a frontend in Angular that access a backend in Java Spring.

Both in my dev computer work well and I can access and run the application in the browser correctly.

Now I need to deploy it to a test server.

I'm deploying both frontend and backend to the same test server in Tomcat \webapps.

In the test server both backend and frontend run on port 8080.

The problem is that when I access the deployed application from my dev machine like this:

`http://testserverip:8080/myapp`

I'm getting this error in Chrome Dev Tools:

`GET http://localhost:8080/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

UPDATE:

I originally thought this was a CORS issue.

But realized it is not because both frontend and backend are running in the same Origin (http://localhost:8080) as both were deployed to the same Test Server, in the same Tomcat installation \webapps and in the same port.

So I'm removing the CORS code from the question.

Now I placed logs in the frontend caller method and in the backend controller method.

It does execute correctly the frontend (the frontend log gets written).

Then it calls the backend controller method.

But backend controller log never gets written.

So it is not getting to the backend.

The issue only happens when accessing the application frontend from the dev machine web browser.

If I log into the test server, open a browser there and access the frontend that way, it executes both frontend and backend correctly.

So what else could be blocking backend to be executed when accessing the front end outside the test server?

Comment: Seems you haven't added `http://testserverip:8080` in `allowedOrigins` you can also try to change `http://testserverip:8080` to   `http://yourdomain.com:8080` and also add it to `allowedOrigins`

Comment: By default, you don't need to configure CORS for same origin request (i.e is both the client and server are on the same origin), until or unless there are restrictions on your server end.

Looking at `GET http://localhost:8080/api 400`, it seems to be returning bad request (400). So, there might be some validations issue (invalid format, syntax, etc) from your end.

Comment: @Eric I have tried adding http://testserverip:8080. In my case it should be the same as adding http://localhost:8080 because both the frontend and backend are in http://localhost:8080. Think Tush is right. Since both are in the same origin looks like the problem is something else, not CORS.

Comment: @Tush That's right. Both are in the same origin. So the problem seems to be something else, not CORS.

Comment: I updated the question removing CORS and providing more context (see section UPDATE)

Comment: @jkfe, have you checked the dev tools? Whether the request gets any response? What is the status code it is returning?
If its 400 bad request, then you need to check the middlewares.

Comment: @Tush Yes, in Chrome Dev Tools sometimes I get the ```net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED``` and sometimes a ```GET 401``` error is returned for the same call. Both of them have just headers and no response at all ```"Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier)
``` for first case and ```"This request has no response data available"``` for the second.

Comment: Looks it's something related to Angular credentials to connect to the backend. Angular ```withCredentials``` is set to true.

Comment: Can you check if the response header contains `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`? And if cookies are being sent in the request?

Comment: @Tush. ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` is present in the Request Header and is set to true. But cookie is in fact not there. Good catch. That happens only when calling the test server version from the dev machine browser. If I call the local dev machine installed version of the app, cookie is in there correctly and everything works well. Why would that be?

Comment: @jkfe, on your local dev machine, the request is same origin or cross origin?

Comment: In local dev it is cross origin. Frontend is on ```http://localhost:4200/``` while backend is on ```http://localhost:8080/```. In test server they are both on the same origin ```http://localhost:8080/```

Comment: @jkfe, That might be the case, I think what's happening is that:

On local dev -> cross origin -> `withCredentials` = true and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` = true.
Hence, cookies were sent successfully.

On test server -> same origin -> `withCredentials` = true and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` = true. Since, its same origin, cookies were not sent, but server expected it. Hence, a bad request.

For the test server (same origin requests) only, try to set `withCredentials` to false.

Comment: I set it to false but getting the same 401 error. ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` continues showing as true in the response header and cookie continues not being displayed.

Comment: Maybe you can also try disabling `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header in the response. That seems to be the last option.

Comment: I can't. I'm using waffle authentication which requires that to be true. I think the last option would be to have two instances of tomcat in the test server and do a cross origin request in the server. But that's one more instance to manage. I would prefer finding a way to produce the cookie even in same origin requests. From what I've been reading ```withCredentials``` generates cookie just for cross origin requests.

Comment: I installed a second instance of Tomcat in a different port in the test server to make a cross origin request. Still getting the same error. ```withCredentials``` set to true. ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` set to true. Cookie still not generated.

Comment: Is it still returning 400/401? Do you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set in the response header?

Comment: I know the reason. The new port is blocked for remote access. I'll check if I can find a way to open it. But better solution would be to have both backend and frontend in the same port.

Comment: @Tush I found the issue! In the angular code I was calling the api this way: ```http://localhost:8080/api```. But that was making a reference to the localhost in the client machine, not the localhost in the server (as I originally imagined it would). When I changed to the actual server ip address ```http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/api``` it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for your support anyways. Very much appreciated. All the best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the above comments, after a lot of time on this I found the issue.

The angular code was calling the rest api this way:
`http://localhost:8080/api`

When I changed it to the actual server ip address it worked perfectly.
`http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/api`

Answer (score 0):

in what path is the file located to change that parameter?

About this:

Like mentioned in the above comments, after a lot of time on this I found the issue.

The angular code was calling the rest api this way: http://localhost:8080/api

When I changed it to the actual server ip address it worked perfectly. http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/api

Comment: I see you just joined the forum. Just so you know, this is not the correct place to add a question about what was written as an answer. Correct place would be to place a comment in my answer. People are pretty tough here and you can end up getting dowvotes for violating rules like this. So recommend you delete this answer that you posted and add a comment there. Anyways, to answer your question, it's in the angular file environment.prod.ts.